# React prop is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new and still learning react. I want to send a prop to another component of mine (in this case I want to send "buttonText" to "name").
My code looks like this:

```
class ChampionList extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      championSelected: false,
      buttonText: 'String',
    }
    this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  _onButtonClick() {
    var button = document.querySelector('button').innerHTML;
    this.setState({
      championSelected: true, 
      buttonText: button,
    });
    console.log(this.props.buttonText);//returns undefined
    console.log(button); //returns Bard

  }
render() {
    return (
      <div className="root">
        <div className="championList-wrapper">

          <button onClick={this._onButtonClick}>Bard</button>
        </div>
        <div className="championSingle-wrapper">
        {this.state.championSelected ?
            <ChampionSingle name={this.buttonText}/> 
           : null}
        </div>
      </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default ChampionList;
```

```
function ChampionSingle(props)  {
    
    return( 
        <div className="single-champion">Hallo {props.name}</div>
        )  
}

export default ChampionSingle
```

As you can see, I want to assign buttonText to the Text of the button (duh) and then give it to  Component to render the  name, but the prop stays undefined.

Comment: Can you share your html? Are you using <ChampionList /> ?

Comment: As a sidenote. If you are new in learning react then start with react hooks with functional compoments.

Comment: Is it `this.buttonText`, `this.state.buttonText`, or `this.props.buttonText`? Make up your mind

Answer (score 1):

Because `this.buttonText` is `undefined`:

```
<ChampionSingle name={this.buttonText}/>
```

The button text is in your state (where it should be):

```
this.state = {
  championSelected: false,
  buttonText: 'String',
}
```

So you'd reference it from state:

```
<ChampionSingle name={this.state.buttonText}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's always the simplest thing I do wrong. Using this.state.buttonText solved it :)